# Правильная работа с pymysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

я хотел бы уточнить по поводу безопасности и в общем правильности подхода к реализации. Правильно ли написан код ниже, соединение после окончания функции закрывается?

```
import pymysql


class DataBase:

    def __init__(self, host, user, password, database):
        self.connection = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, db=database)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()


    def select_all(self):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
            return self.cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

я бы попробовал так:

```
import pymysql


class DataBase:
    def __init__(self, host, user, password, database):
        super().__init__()

        self.host = host 
        self.user = user 
        self.password = password 
        self.database = database

        self.sqlConnect()
        self.select_all()

    def sqlConnect(self):
        try:
            self.connection = pymysql.connect(
                host=self.host, 
                user=self.user, 
                password=self.password, 
                db=self.database
            )
        except:            
            print("ErrorConnect ")
            exit(1)

        print("Connect ")
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def select_all(self, cmd="show tables"):
#        with self.connection:
        cmd = "SELECT * FROM users"
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.cursor.execute(self.cmd)
        self.connection.commit()

        return self.cursor.fetchall()

    def closeEvent(self):                   # закройте когда вам надо будет
        print("Close! ")
        self.connection.close()
```